# JMeter 3.3: Cannot read variables from file - Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Let me give a bit of background.

As you can see, two variables are defined that point to two different *.ini files using the following value:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}Settings.ini
```

for variable: **SettingsFile**

Using Step-by-step debugger, I can confirm that the path to the files is correct. Now, the fun part.
I have few "User Defined Variables" that read values from the files.

JMeter cannot read values for this variables and throws the following error for each one of them:

using (e.g): for variable *accountNumber*

```
2018-02-20 15:15:46,750 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``{import org.ini4j.*; Wini ini = new Wini(new File(vars.get("SettingsFile"))); St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace
2018-02-20 15:15:46,751 WARN o.a.j.f.BeanShell: Error running BSH script
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``{import org.ini4j.*; Wini ini = new Wini(new File(vars.get("SettingsFile"))); St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.eval(BeanShellInterpreter.java:189) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.BeanShell.execute(BeanShell.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:92) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument.getValue(Argument.java:146) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments.getArgumentsAsMap(Arguments.java:94) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.createArgumentsMap(PreCompiler.java:114) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.addNode(PreCompiler.java:101) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996) [jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978) [jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:369) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: bsh.EvalError: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``{import org.ini4j.*; Wini ini = new Wini(new File(vars.get("SettingsFile"))); St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace
    at bsh.BSHAmbiguousName.toClass(BSHAmbiguousName.java:74) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.BSHType.getType(BSHType.java:154) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.java:75) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728) ~[bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    ... 14 more
```

The Settings.ini looks like (taken accountNumber as an example):

```
[General]
    ;account number used for testing
    accountNumber = 989899773
    ;BadAccountNumber = 12314500
    BadAccountNumber = 989899773
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error? I do not understand why I cannot read the values for each variable if the path to the file is correct.

PS: I don't get any results in "View Results Tree". All tests are simple HTTP requests using variables from the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to missing [ini4j library](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/download.html), you need to download the .jar, put it somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick the .jar up.

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting in JMeter. So consider to moving to Groovy on next available opportunity. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, this was the problem.